# Program into infinite loop -Java

Tags: java, loops, netbeans

I am trying to solve a problem using java where I have to print the number the same number of time as the number itself. For example 1 will be printed once 2 twice 3 thrice and so on. I tried to attempt the question using nested loop but it is going into infinite loop. Please pinpoint the mistake in the code.
Thanks!

```
 {                                         
    for (int i=1;i<=10;i=i+1) {
        for (int j=1;j<=i; j=i) {
            jTextArea1.append(""+j);
        }
    }
 }
```

P.S I attempted this question using netbeans.

Comment: `j=i` will give you infinite loop

Comment: Be very careful in the future when working with iteration. Understand why this won't ever stop (until j overflows...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is in the second loop.**

Making progress as **j=i** and checking for **j<=i** will always give the **true** result. So there is the infinite loop.

You may want to change the progress to something like `j= j+1`

**Edit:** You need to do this

```
for (int i=1;i<=10;i=i+1) {
    for (int j=1;j<=i; j++) {
         jTextArea1.append(""+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! I would like you to clarify as if why we are printing i and not j as the output? I am really sorry for this trivial question but I am new to java programming. Thanks!

Comment: @sam007 that depends on your need. See by using __j__ instead and see the result. So choose what ever you need in your program. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused in second loop during initialize `j = i`. This interrupt the var `j` to be increment. It should be `j++` or `j += 1` or `j = j + 1`. Example here...

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
       jTextArea1.append(" "+i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this see what is happening. I've simplified your code a bit:

```
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
   for (int j=1; j<i; j=i){
      System.out.println("j=" + j + ", i=" + i);
   }
}
```